# Can I use server-side props from getServerSideProps to initialize dynamic state in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm currently creating a simple application using NextJS and I'm wondering what the best way is to handle SSR using data from an API that will also be dynamic on the page. My current approach is outlined as follows, and I'm curious as to whether this is how it should be done in NextJS.

I retrieve a set of todos from the free JSON Placeholder API using `getServerSideProps` inside of my `Home` page component as follows (please note that I'm using TypeScript):

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  const todoAPIResponse = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=10');
  const todos = await todoAPIResponse.json();

  return {
    props: {
      todos,
    },
  };
};
```

The `Home` component is defined as:

```
const Home: NextPage = ({ todos }: HomeProps) => {

  const [todoState, setTodoState] = useState(todos);
  const [newTodo, setNewTodo] = useState('');

  const onSubmit = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTodoState((prev: any) => [...prev, { title: newTodo }]);
    setNewTodo('');
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {todoState.map((todo: any) => <p key={todo.id}>{todo.title}</p>)}
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input value={newTodo} onChange={(event) => setNewTodo(event.target.value)} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

As you can see inside of the `Home` component, I am initializing `todoState` using the props (the data retrieved from the API), and then the data becomes dynamic with the ability to create new todos with the form. In the typical "React way", I understand that the todos would be initialized as an empty array, then inside of a `useEffect`, the API could be called and then the state could be set from there, however, I'm trying to understand what the proper way of doing this in NextJS is as I am new to the framework and the concept of SSR.

Comment: Yes, you can certainly do that.

Comment: Your way looks good to me. Just remember adding `id` when adding new todo to your state.
`setTodoState((prev: any) => [...prev, { title: newTodo, id: "ADD ID HERE" }]);`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are doing it right.

The approach between ssr and react is different. In the ssr version, you need a server first, so that each call to this page would make this `fetch` before a HTML page is assembled and sent back to the *UI*. And afterwards, the *NextJS* will hydrate this page to make it like a regular *React* page by attaching all the other dynamic attributes.